# Change masterpage item label depending on app authentication

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

In my xamarin forms app - I want a button on the masterpage to say 'Login'  when the user is not logged in. Once the user is logged in I want the same button to say 'Logout'.

I have made a masterpageitem class utilising INotifyPropertyChanged. 
I have created an ObservableCollection masterPageItems. 
I have listView.ItemsSource = App.masterPageItems;

//masterpageitem.cs

```
public class MasterPageItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string title;
    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return title;
        }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("title");
        }
    }

    public string IconSource { get; set; }

    public Type TargetType { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string info)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(info));
    }
}
```

//App.xaml.cs

```
public static ObservableCollection<MasterPageItem> masterPageItems = new ObservableCollection<MasterPageItem>
        {
            new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Home",
                IconSource = "home.png",
                TargetType = typeof(HomePage)
            },
            new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = "Competitions",
                IconSource = "logo.png",
                TargetType = typeof(Views.PlayerTournaments)
            },
            new MasterPageItem
            {
                Title = App.authenticated?"Sign out":"Sign in",
                IconSource = "logo.png",
                TargetType = typeof(LoginPage)
            }
        };
```

//Masterpage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MasterPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListView ListView { get { return listView; } }


    public MasterPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listView.ItemsSource = App.masterPageItems;
    }
```

//Masterpage.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="listView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <Grid Padding="5,10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image Source="{Binding IconSource}" />
                        <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Title}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

//LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
void UpdateSignInState(UserContext userContext)
    {
        var isSignedIn = userContext.IsLoggedOn;
        btnSignInSignOut.Text = isSignedIn ? "Sign out" : "Sign in";
        App.authenticated = isSignedIn;
        App.masterPageItems[2].Title = App.authenticated ? "Sign out" : "Sign in";
    }
```

When I log out - the masterpage item remains "Sign Out" when I want it to say "Sign in"

Comment: `NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");` - your property is capital-T "Title" not "title"

Comment: Thanks for that. Working correctly now.